# Private Files and corrupted files

Tags: files

Hello fellow Drupal expert,

I'm in search of wisdom. Some said i can find it in here :)

Okay so here's my issue. We got an intranet and we'd like to have some privacy (if you know what i mean). We're using IMCE and a module called private_file_download_permission (so we can map our existing roles to folders). But nothing is working, we can set private folders (and control their access) but every file we upload (through IMCE)is being corrupted.

Let me explain cause i've found some interesting things. First, if i download my file through FTP it work well. But if i go through the website it is corrupted. So I looked around and find that when i open my file with a text editor there's 2 empty lines added to it and if i delete them the file goes back to normal. But remember this happen only when the file is put on a private folder (works fine on public ones).

Have you some idea of what kind of sorcery is going on ?

Sorry for my english, and thank you for your answer;
Rémi

Comment: Are files corrupted on the server? If you upload them, and then download using sftp, they are changed? If you upload them with minimalistic PHP + html form, they are broken too, or then they are OK?

Comment: Tried that and the answer is the files are good. I feel like this is a request issue or some module messing around :/

Comment: If files are OK on the server's HDD, you can pretty much remove all that upload description, saying that upload works and files gets corrupted on download. It will severely reduce noise in your question and make it easier to parse :)

Comment: Sorry i just explain my issue the way i lived it. I could have cut some part but then you won't have the full story and you might have miss some information. The thing is i don't know where is the issue i've just collected pieces of what's wrong.

Comment: If files are OK on the server, we know upload is not an issue. If files are corrupted on server, we know upload is exactly the issue. Either way, you can cut it in half pretty fast. And this is not a support site. This is Q&A. It means we don't want your full story, we only want what's relevant to your question. If half of it is irrelevant and you can know which part, then please test, and remove irrelevant data. For clarity.

Comment: Ok i understand your point.
So you can't help because my question isn't clear (because i can't take out a clear issue).

thank you for your help and have a good day :)

Comment: Sadly yes. This requires some debug only you can do. When you will cut it down, we might be able to help.

Comment: How big are the files? Are there any errors in your http logs? A private file download could reach the timeout limit of PHP, but not necessarily show you that error in the browser.

Comment: Ok, the problem happen on every type of files (big or not), and there is no error on the logs.

Comment: Is it possible that this is some kind of ?> related bug in one or two modules?

Answer (score 2):

Ok my colleague found the solution !!

There was 2 lines added at the start of our settings.php :

This thing added lines at our downloaded files and corrupted them  !!

Ok so thank you for your time :)